# Struts reads UTF-8 encoded Resourcebundles as ISO-8859

Tags: java, jsp, encoding, utf-8, struts

I have the honorable assignment to change the encoding of our complete workspace, projects and files to the UTF-8 encoding. We have several Resourcebundles which used to code special chars with unicode. We also wanted to get rid of that unicode stuff by switching to UTF-8 so I changed the encoding of the Resourcebundles (.properties) files too and replaced the Unicode characters.

We also have german resourcebundles and some chars like

Ä, Ö, Ü, ß. ä, ö, ü and also special characters like „ or “

are not shown properly in the browser.

struts-config.xml:

```
<!-- Nachrichtenressourcen -->
<message-resources parameter="resources.ApplicationResources"/>
```

JSP-Code:

```
<td><bean-el:message key="session.expired" arg0="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index.html" /></td>
```

Bundle entry:

```
session.expired= Ihre Sitzung ist abgelaufen. Bitte kehren Sie zur Login-Seite zurück.
```

The "ü" is displayed wrong in the browser. due to the issue that Struts(Java) assumes the Properties file is ISO-8859 encoded.

I already checked the the page contentType and set a global configuration parameter in the web.xml jsp-config -->

```
<page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
```

Is there a way to tell Struts to read the Bundles as UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: Properties files are always ISO-8859-1.

Comment: I know this. I am seeking an ideea to get rid of the unicode stuff.

Comment: Are you creating the resource bundles appropriately? There aren't really any problems with I18N in Java or S2.

Comment: yes the bundles are created correctly. And Struts is also working fine with them i am looking for an option to read the bundles as UTF-8 and not ISO8859.

Comment: I have the same problem and would also like to have Struts use the values as UTF-8.